# Collectionview dynamic height change with constraints not working in Swift

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, height, cell

I am using collectionview in tableview cell and the hierarchy of tableview cell is like this

[image]

topview constraints `top = 0, leading = 0, trailing = 0, bottom => 0`

ViewX constraints `top = 0 leading = 0, trailing = 0, bottom => 10`

collectionviewViewX constraints `top => 10 to ViewX, leading = 0, trailing = 0, bottom = 10`

Attatchments collectionview constraints `top = 10 to label, leading = 0, trailing = 0, bottom = 10, height = 50`

Stackview constraints `top = 10, leading = 0, trailing = 0, bottom = 10, height = 50`

**and tableview cell code**: but with this code collectionview height is not changing according to cells count.. how to change collectionview height according to number of cells coming from JSON

```
 class ProposalTableVIewCell: UITableViewCell, UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var attCollHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet weak var attetchmentsCollectionview: UICollectionView!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.scrollDirection = .vertical
          layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
          layout.minimumLineSpacing = 5
    let width = UIScreen.main.bounds.width/2.5
            let height = CGFloat(40)
            layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: width, height: height)
          self.attetchmentsCollectionview.collectionViewLayout = layout
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return attachArray?.count ?? 0
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "AttatchmentCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! AttatchmentCollectionViewCell

    var attatchBid = attachArray?[indexPath.item]

    self.attCollHeight.constant = collectionView.contentSize.height

    return cell
}

}
```

**o/p**  there are 10 cells.. but hear all cells are not showing.. how to show all cells please do help me.. i got stuck here from long

[image]

**EDIT:** according to below answer o/p coming like this.. how to move cell to left side.. currently cell in the middle

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
super.awakeFromNib()

let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
layout.scrollDirection = .vertical
      layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
      layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0

let width = UIScreen.main.bounds.width/2.1
        let height = CGFloat(40)
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: width, height: height)
      self.attetchmentsCollectionview.collectionViewLayout = layout
 }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your table's `cellForRow` and check if it works:

```
  cell.frame = tableView.bounds
        cell.layoutIfNeeded()
        cell.attetchmentsCollectionview.reloadData()
        cell.attCollHeight.constant = cell.attetchmentsCollectionview.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize.height;
```

**EDIT:**

Left aligned cell and 1 item per row, add this delegate method:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    
    let flowLayout = collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
    
    return UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: collectionView.frame.width - flowLayout.itemSize.width)
}
```

Comment: thank u so much.. i have accepted ur answer.. but can pls guide me here.. i have added my updated code at the End of my post.. how to move collectionview cell to the left side.. currently its in middle

Comment: please try do answer here as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68725339/how-to-make-collectionview-cell-come-close-to-another-cell-in-swift